# ExtJS model raw data is not synced with actual record upon load

Tags: extjs, model, store, synchronization

I have a model

```
Ext.define('MyCompany.model.Customer', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
        'id', 'name', 'taxID', 'tradeID', 'vatID', 'email'
    ]
}
```

and a store

```
Ext.define('MyCompany.store.Customers', {
    extend: 'MyCompany.lib.base.Store',

    model: 'MyCompany.model.Customer',

    api: {
        read: $["crmModule.CustomerController"].list,
        create: $["crmModule.CustomerController"].save
    }
});
```

The problem is that upon calling `store.load()` (e.g. from the console), the field `vatID` is not synced. I can see the field in `store.data.items[0].raw`, but in `store.data.items[0].data` the field is empty. How can I debug this issue? Where does ExtJS does the conversion from raw data to the actual records?

Answer (score 0):

Look for the method named `extractData` defined for `Ext.data.reader.Reader`. There are following lines:

```
// If the server did not include an id in the response data, the Model constructor will mark the record as phantom.
// We  need to set phantom to false here because records created from a server response using a reader by definition are not phantom records.
record.phantom = false;

// Use generated function to extract all fields at once
me.convertRecordData(convertedValues, node, record);

records.push(record);
```

When you step into the method `convertRecordData`, you will be presented with the generated temporary code for actual conversion like the following:

```
return function(dest, source, record) {
    value = source["id"];
    if (value !== undefined) {
        dest["id"] = value;
    }
    value = source["name"];
    if (value === undefined) {
        if (me.applyDefaults) {
    ...
```